# Unpack sequences from Numpy Array

Tags: arrays, numpy, tuples, sequence, python-2.6

I've got a numpy array in which the elements are sequences, like:

```
freq_chan = [  1.00000000e-01   1.88670219e-01  -7.54695562e-03   2.62096706e-13
  -2.13348799e-14   1.03343348e+00  -4.13380390e-02   2.62973944e-02
  -1.05194953e-03   3.40951940e-13  -2.68000220e-14   1.44764659e+00
  -5.79069851e-02  -1.65709468e-01   6.62852413e-03  -3.55350204e-14
   3.45455226e-15   7.39936927e-01  -2.95981613e-02]
[  2.99900000e-01   1.88684850e-01  -7.54812794e-03   2.42380739e-12
  -1.94552116e-13   1.03357295e+00  -4.13492157e-02   2.63081045e-02
  -1.05280780e-03   2.96306692e-12  -2.36910642e-13   1.44787002e+00
  -5.79248893e-02  -1.65738440e-01   6.63084580e-03  -4.40512728e-13
   3.59021896e-14   7.40073244e-01  -2.96090852e-02]
```

However, each element of the sequence is supposed to be an element of the main matrix, like

```
freq_chan = [  1.00000000e-01   1.88670219e-01  -7.54695562e-03   2.62096706e-13 -2.13348799e-14   1.03343348e+00  -4.13380390e-02   2.62973944e-02 -1.05194953e-03   3.40951940e-13  -2.68000220e-14   1.44764659e+00 -5.79069851e-02  -1.65709468e-01   6.62852413e-03  -3.55350204e-14 -5.79069851e-02  -1.65709468e-01   6.62852413e-03  -3.55350204e-14 3.45455226e-15   7.39936927e-01  -2.95981613e-02]
```

So, for example, that freq_chan[0,1] should return 1.88670219e-01. Right now freq_chan[0,2] returns the error:

```
    print(freq_chan[0,2])
    TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple.
```

This Numpy array is created from a python list of tuples using the code:

```
for i,j in enumerate(freq_chan):
    freq_chan[i] = np.array(freq_chan[i], dtype = float)
```

Is there a way to create this Numpy array so that elements of the tuples are unpacked?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure freq_chan is a np.array?

Comment: Shouldnt np.array(freq_chan_unfolded[i], dtype = float) make it a numpy array

Comment: I am not talking about freq_chan_unfolded, but freq_chan.

Comment: freq_chan_unfolded should be freq_chan. See edited comment

Comment: `freq_chan[0,2]` or `freq_chan[0,1]`?

Comment: yeah, sorry, freq_chan[0,1]

Comment: Also, your freq_chan definition is unclear, are some brackets missing?

Comment: Just do `np.asarray(freq_chan)` or `np.array(freq_chan)` and then index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now `freq_chan` is not a `np.array`, but a list of np arrays (hence your error: you can't index list with tuples). Outside of your loop, you must do `freq_chan = np.array(freq_chan)`; then `freq_chan` will be a 2D `np.array` and you'll be able to index it with [0, 1].

See that the type of a does not change in my example:

```
In[52]: a = [[ 0, 1], [2, 3]]

In[51]: type(a)
Out[51]: list  

In[52]: for i in range(len(a)):
            a[i] = np.array(a[i])

        type(a)
Out[52]: list

In[53]: a[0, 1]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-55-e56b75b8ad1b>", line 1, in <module>
    a[0, 1]

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple


In[54]: a = np.array(a)

In[55]: a[0, 1]
Out[55]: 1
```

Comment: I've tried to unpack the elements as                                                                                                                              f=np.zeros((len(freq_chan),10))                                for i,j in enumerate(freq_chan):
                             
                             for x,y in enumerate(j):
                                 
                                 f[i,x] = float(y)                                                                          But it returns the error:     f[i,x] = y
 index 10 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 10

Comment: Well this is a different question. If my question solved your previous problem, please mark it as accepted and post a new quesition.

Comment: Yes, for i,j in enumerate(freq_chan): for x,y in enumerate(j): f[i,x] = float(y) sorted the unpacking of the arrays. The only thing was that my length of f was incorrect,